# Chopsticks On Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Are you permitted to Break apart the Chopsticks to use them On Shabbos?

Comment: What about to take the chop sticks and make them usable for those that normally can't use them (taking the paper the come in, folding it up and attaching it to the top with a rubber band. This is also mistama maka b'patish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remember to break your chopsticks and
>   open the packaging before Shabbos.
>   Thank you.

[http://www.sushiagogo.com/perplexed.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20101026000155/http://www.sushiagogo.com/perplexed.html)

Comment: I love the source!!

Comment: ST, is this an authoritative source? It may be cute, but for Halacha, how can you love such a "source"?

Answer (score 11):

Wouldn't it be a clearcut case of "makeh b'patish" (putting the final touch on an object to make it usable)? The chopsticks clearly aren't usable for their intended purpose while they're attached together.

Answer (score 2):

This is Uvda d'Chol, as defined by Mishna Berura 314:48. (his point there about this being Uvda D'Chol when one breaks wood into large pieces is only to avoid Tochein (grinding) and is not a 'shiur'that would absolve to complete chop-sticks)